# How setup template file for chart tooltip?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I use angularJS and kendo.
How setup template (separated) for chart tooltip ?

```
<div id="buildLogChart" kendo-chart
     k-tooltip="{ visible: true, template: '#TooltipTemplate' }">
</div>
```

Comment: angulartJS, not angularJS ?

Comment: what do you mean by "template (separated) for chart tooltip"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `k-tooltip="tooltipOptions"` where on your controller define `$scope.tooltipOptions` then you can simply set the template from your controller like for example

```
$scope.tooltipOptions =  {
      visible :true,
      template : "<div id='testId' class='testClass' style='font-size:15px;'>\
                     <div>${series.name}</div>\
                     <div>${series.color}</div>\
                     <div>${value}</div>\
                  </div>"
};
```

Explanation :

- You can pretty much use id class or inline css to suit your styling(the content of the tooltip)
  needs
- The list of information  you can acess from within is listed [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/chart/tooltip)
- Dont forget to add '\' if you intend to create a multiline otherwise
  you need to finish it in 1 line(bad for readabilty though)

And Finally here's

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/alUZi)

Also if you want to put it on separate file (i'm not sure if i got your question 100%), you can use kendo template by creating a page and add a kendo template script

```
<script id="customTooltipTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div id='testId' class='testClass' style='font-size:15px; color:black; background-color:white;'>
        <div>${series.name}</div>
        <div>${series.color}</div>
        <div>${value}</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Then import/link the file to your controller then you can use it like :

```
$scope.tooltipOptions =  {
    visible :true,
    template : kendo.template($("#customTooltipTemplate").html())
};
```

And Finally here's

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/alUZi/2)

NOTE: i'm not creating it on a separate file because i obviously can't do it here on kendo dojo, but this kendo template can be placed on other page but you need to import/link the file to your current file first. Read more about kendo template [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview)

Comment: Thanks. why you use ${}, I use #: #